# Code crushing with header php with dual slider bar JS code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to use dual slider bar

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

And using the dual slider bar in HTML code is down below

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="price-min">Price:</label>
    <input type="range"  id="age_min" name = "age_min" value="18" min="18" max="100">
    <label for="price-max">Price:</label>
    <input type="range"  id="age_max" name = "age_max"value="30" min="0" max="100">
</div>
```

and send value to server.php

```
<button type="submit" name = "btn_preference" >Submit</button>
```

Database is already created

Send it value to PHP

And when Validation is OKAY

```
header('location: ../index.php');
```

Header code in PHP server re-direct the location to index.php page

The code is able to save data to database through SQL code.

However, the page can not re-directing to index.php

```
if (count($errors) == 0) 
  {
    $query = "UPDATE preference
              SET age_min = '$age_min', age_max='$age_max'
          WHERE email = '$email'";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    header('location: index.php');
  }
```

If i have the code header('location: ../index.php');

The page just stop in same page However data going into database

When i remove header('location: ../index.php');

Page working well.

Comment: _When i remove header('location: ../index.php');..._ I don't see any `header('location: ../index.php');` as you've just posted html

Comment: Ensure `header('location: ../index.php');` is put before you output anything to the page.

Comment: @B001ᛦ sorry i missed.. now i am edited. would you please have a look again?

Comment: @Profit I edited. Would you please have a look again?

Comment: Have you tried the code using `exit()` after `header(...)`?

Comment: @B001ᛦ If i used exit, the page showed nothing. However i can see the changed. ... it work .. but it's not work..

Comment: @B001ᛦ Sorry mistake. If i put exit() after header(). It does not change nothing..

Comment: Do you `echo` before header() somewhere in your code?